# How to write an SQL NOT EXISTS query/scope in the Rails way?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rdbms, not-exists

I have a database scope to filter only latest `ProxyConfig` version for particular `Proxy` and `environment`.

This is the raw SQL that works very well with MySQL, PostgreSQL and Oracle:

```rb
class ProxyConfig < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  scope :current_versions, -> do
    where %(NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM proxy_configs pc
      WHERE proxy_configs.environment = environment
        AND proxy_configs.proxy_id = proxy_id
        AND proxy_configs.version < version
      ))
  end
  ...
end
```

You can find a simple test case in my [baby_squeel issue](https://github.com/rzane/baby_squeel/issues/123).

But I find it nicer not to use SQL directly. I have spent a lot of time trying out different approaches to write it in the Rails way to no avail. I found generic Rails and baby_squeel examples but they always involved different tables.

PS The previous version used `joins` but it was super slow and it messed up some queries. For example `#count` produced an SQL syntax error. So I'm not very open on using other approaches. Rather I prefer to know how to implement this query exactly. Although I'm at least curious to see other simple solutions.

PPS About the question that direct SQL is fine. In this case, mostly yes. Maybe all RDBMS can understand this quoting. If one needs to compare `text` fields though that requires special functions on Oracle. On Postgres the case-insensitive `LIKE` is `ILIKE`. It can be handled automatically by `Arel`. In raw SQL it would require different string for the different RDBMS.

Comment: ActiveRecord is not a very good SQL builder; it feels like it's designed for people who don't know SQL and don't want to know. There's probably some way to bend it to do what you want, but I've found it's often fine to use raw SQL instead. Your SQL is clear to someone who knows SQL.

Comment: To your PPS, yes, there are non-standard bits of SQL however there's nothing in *your* SQL that isn't extremely standard. There's no quoting, no `like` (ActiveRecord doesn't handle `like` anyway), simple text equality doesn't require a special function. Just because *some* SQL is non-standard doesn't mean you have to always avoid raw SQL. You pick and choose when raw SQL is ok.

Comment: @Schwern, one never knows, see this for "simple text equality" - https://github.com/yahonda/oracle-enhanced/commit/dc42c574665d777550c93e6b304dbaf3af08d1ca

Comment: The thing I've learned about Rails is that, in most cases, the schema and model are wielded together and are supposed to change together. While a certain amount of effort to keep the SQL generic is good, "what if we switch to Oracle and start using CLOBs" is [wasted effort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost). Rails won't even make a CLOB. One does know.

Comment: @Schwern, for me this is not hypothetical, my project does support mysql, postgresql and oracle (unfortunately). Also Rails does create a CLOBs for `text` fields on oracle. With this query specifically though, that is not needed. I find it good to know how to do this when I need.

Comment: Excuse me, I missed that. That requirement could be more clear in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't actually a query that you can build with the ActiveRecord Query Interface alone. It can be done with a light sprinkling of Arel though:

```ruby
class ProxyConfig < ApplicationRecord
  def self.current_versions
    pc = arel_table.alias("pc")
    where(
      unscoped.select(1)
         .where(pc[:environment].eq(arel_table[:environment]))
         .where(pc[:proxy_id].eq(arel_table[:proxy_id]))
         .where(pc[:version].gt(arel_table[:version]))
         .from(pc)
         .arel.exists.not
    )
  end
end
```

The generated SQL isn't identical but I think it should be functionally equivilent.

```sql
SELECT "proxy_configs".* FROM "proxy_configs" 
WHERE NOT (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM "proxy_configs" "pc" 
    WHERE "pc"."environment" = "proxy_configs"."environment" 
    AND "pc"."proxy_id" = "proxy_configs"."proxy_id" 
    AND "pc"."version" > "proxy_configs"."version"
  )
)
```

Comment: I would agree with Schwern though that its often perfectly acceptable to use SQL strings and its often much more readible then Arel.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually very nice. I tried similar things but not using direct arel methods, instead I used `something: arel_table...` approach and it generated bad SQL.

There are a few small things I had to change in your answer to work: `unscoped.select(1)...`, comparison should be `#gt` and to be a `scope`. But other than that this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot again. Can you edit your answer with the minor corrections or I can do if you don't mind?

Comment: The reason I didn't use scope is that its just syntactic sugar for defining a class method and multi-line lambdas are horrible for readibilty. IMHO it should only be used for oneliners. Your also using < in your question.

Comment: My personal opinion is that when it is a `scope` it is clear that it can be used as a `scope` while a method may or may not be chainable. But that is fine. The `unscoped` and `gt` changes are needed though for this to work as a chained scope (be it defined in a method or not). wrt SQL vs arel, when working with multiple databases, I find beneficial to have in code. If not for anything else, for not thinking about proper quoting. Also if `#matches` and more complicated methods are used, things can become ugly especially on oracle (even simple comparison of `text` fields is ugly).

Comment: `unscope` is a pretty good point - you could also use `ProxyConfig.select(1)` to explicitly build the query off the class instead of "the chain". I see the tradeoff between Arel and SQL as basically portability and composability vs readibilty and how insanely frustrating it can be at times to get Arel to generate some pretty basic SQL structures like for example `COUNT(*) FILTER WHERE id > 5` .